# how to place functions in main file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a small question, i have created functions for zoom, NNi, bilenear for displaying picture that is:

zoom.m

```
function [out]= zoom(n,factor)
-----
---
----
end
```

NNI.m

```
function [out]= NNI(n,factor)
-----
---
----
end
```

Bilenear.m

```
function [out]= Bilenear(n,factor)
-----
---
----
end
```

what i am trying:
main.m

```
function [out]= answer(n, factor)
clc
function [out]= zoom(n,factor)
function [out]= NNI(n,factor)
function [out]= Bilenear(n,factor)
end
```

i want this main function to display zoomed picture, nni pic and bilenear separately

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: if you want to show different figures, just type figure before using imshow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on Schorsch's answer since you mention you want your main function to display these images you could try something like the following:

```
function [out] = compare_interpolations(n,factor)
clc
zoomed = zoom(n,factor);
nearest= NNI(n,factor);
bilinterp=Bilinear(n,factor);

figure;
subplot(1,3,1);imshow(zoomed);title('Zoomed');
subplot(1,3,2);imshow(nearest);title('Nearest Neighbor');
subplot(1,3,3);imshow(bilinterp);title('Bilinear');


end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question but you don't call functions with the `function` command.
Maybe try this in `main.m`:

```
function [out]= answer(n, factor)

clc
[out1]= zoom(n,factor)
[out2]= NNI(n,factor)
[out3]= Bilenear(n,factor)

out = NaN;

end
```

Make sure that the other `.m`-files are saved in the same directory or in your Matlab-search-path (Matlab has to find these functions).
Also, make sure that `answer` in `main.m` actually provides a return argument `out`. I set it to `NaN` in this example, but you could also return the three `out`s from the other functions:

```
function [out1, out2, out3] = answer(n, factor)
```